# How to check if user has already liked my facebook page without authentification?

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

I would like to setup a hotspot (free Internet access) with a splash page, a facebook like button is place on the splash page allow the user to like my facebook page before they can access to the internet.

I'm using Javascript as below to detect if a user has clicked on the button, however the button is not trigger if the user is already liked my Facebook page.

```
<script>
   FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', page_like_or_unlike_callback);
   FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', page_like_or_unlike_callback);
</script>
```

Is there a way to trigger the like button even though Facebook user is already liked my Facebook page without user permission?